# Android Studio gets stuck at Building 'Project_Name' Gradle project info even after Re-Installing on completely formatted Mac

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed android studio 2.3.3 on my Mac and it cannot create any new project. It gets stuck at Building 'Project_Name' Gradle project info. I waited for long time but it does not go ahead. I deleted .gradle folder and then tried still the problem persists. I Even tried re-installing android studio but then again the same problem. So at last I formatted my Mac and then installed studio then also it gives me same problem.

Comment: Have you connected to internet ?

Comment: yeah I am connected to internet @AbhishekAryan

Comment: There is downloading of Gradle going on at the background. Just wait for it to finish. make sure you've good internet connection

Comment: Try to download latest  sdk-platform only not all SDKs

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. It must be downloading gradle distribution in background which can take some time. To check if it is downloading gradle or not, do the following:

- Kill all the instances of android studio first or just restart the computer.
- launch android studio using terminal and keep it open.
- Create a project and now when you see it is stuck, go back to
  terminal and it should show the progress for gradle download.

Comment: how do I check progress for grade download in terminal after new project creation

Comment: After launching android studio from terminal, keep terminal open and when it starts building project, go back to terminal window and it should display the progress automatically. Another thing you can do is observe network monitor for download speed and if no other program is using internet but download speed is still at peak and android studio is building the project then it is most probably android studio is downloading some stuff. So, wait till download speed drops to zero.

Answer (score 0):

First time, It take time because it downloads all the artifact that are required by your project. Internet speed may be the reason.

---

Try this on Mac :

From your HomeScreen of Android Studio

Android Studio -> `preference`  -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will make the gradle build 90% faster.

Comment: check your network/proxy preferences and make sure it's set up properly.

Comment: proxy preferences are also set up properly. still the same issue